# How to use structure array like flexible with c++

Tags: c++

What should I do if I want to use the structure array flexibly? I made my code like below, and tried Triangle and Rectangular.. Triangle was success but when i tried Rectangular I got error messages.

So I tried to change my structure array more flexibly but I don't know how PLZ help !

**polygon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct C2D {
    double x, y;
};

class Polygon {
    int point;
    vector<C2D> arr;
public:
    Polygon(int point_, C2D arr_[]) : arr(point_) {
        point = point_;
        memcpy(arr.data(), arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };
    Polygon(Polygon& p) : arr(p.point) {
        point = p.point;
        memcpy(arr.data(), p.arr.data(), sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };
    Polygon(Polygon&& p) {
        point = p.point;
        memcpy(arr.data(), p.arr.data(), sizeof(C2D) * point);
        p.point = 0;
        delete[]p.arr.data();
    };
    void print() const {
        cout << "Polygon information" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
            cout << i + 1<< "point" << " : " << arr[i].x << ", " << arr[i].y << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    };

    double area_result() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < point; i++) {
            sum += ccw(arr[0].x, arr[i - 1].x, arr[i].x, arr[0].y, arr[i - 1].y, arr[i].y);
        }
        return fabs(sum);
    }

    static double ccw(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3) {
        double res = x1 * y2 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1;
        res += (-y1 * x2 - y2 * x3 - y3 * x1);
        return res / 2;
    }

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    int point;
    C2D c2d[3];

    cout << "point : ";
    cin >> point;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "x : ";
        cin >> c2d[i].x;
        cout << i + 1 << "y : ";
        cin >> c2d[i].y;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    Polygon p(point, c2d);
    p.print();

    cout << "Polygon area : " << p.area_result() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"use the structure array flexibly"_? _"I got error messages"_ What error messages? `memcpy(arr.data(), arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point);` won't work if `point` is larger than `arr.size()`. It won't resize the vector.

Comment: `delete[]p.arr.data();` don't do that!!! The vector will deallocate the memory.

Comment: A vector carries its own length information; you don't really need `Polygon::point`, and your copy and move constructors could be simpler by just assigning `Polygon::arr` . That said, I don't see Triangle or Rectangle in your code, and please post full compile error messages if that's what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two errors.

1. include cmath. It is better to use std::abs(sum) in function area_result() in accordance with cmath.
2. Major error is from the third line of main():
   C2D  c2d[3];
   It fixed the array length of c2d to 3, which causes the segment fault for 4-point polygon.

To fix this error, you may use  *new*  allocate the array c2d as follows:

```
C2D *c2d;
```

And then after red in the number of point, dynamical allocate memories for c2d:

```
c2d = new C2D [point];
```

This fixes your problem. At the final of main(), use  *delete [] c2d*  to delelte the allocation.

As a suggestion, you can place the reading coodinates of polygon in cin overload (or a read member function). That will save a lot efforts as what you are doing here: read data into c2d, and then initial the data to members of polygon with constructor.